# Android : Open activity from other apps

Tags: android

I have an activity, which I want to open from other applications like browser, messaging, adobe reader, etc
For browser I know, I have to put intent filter:
android.intent.category.BROWSABLE
Can Someone help me with what to do to open with other apps.

Comment: your question is not clear, what exactly you want to ask, can you explain more please.

Answer (score 0):

In your mainfest.xml add an intent filter to your activity node:

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will make the ShareActivity show up in a list when another app sends an action.send intent.

Here you find the possible standard intent actions :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: I want to show popup, whenever user long presses any word inside browser app, adobe reader, chrome, messaging etc. Will this going to work ?

Comment: No, you obviously have no control over other apps, you can just make your app respond to intents send by other apps.